# Zend Framework Routing with additional page-param

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

i have a blog with a routing. In my ini it seems like this:

```
routes.quote.route = :id
routes.quote.defaults.module = default
routes.quote.defaults.controller = posts
routes.quote.defaults.action = single
routes.quote.reqs.id = \d+
```

Now i want to have a page parameter (for comments) additionally. I only got it by creating a sectond route like this:

```
routes.quotePage.route = :id/page/:page
routes.quotePage.defaults.module = default
routes.quotePage.defaults.controller = posts
routes.quotePage.defaults.action = single
routes.quotePage.reqs.id = \d+
routes.quotePage.reqs.page = \d+
```

I want to combine these two into one. How can i do this? the page-parameter should only be additional.

Thank You

Answer (score -1):

use [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex](http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex) like this :

```
routes.quote.route.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.quote.route = posts/(\d+)/(\d+)
routes.quote.defaults.module = default
routes.quote.defaults.controller = posts
routes.quote.defaults.action = single
routes.quote.map.1 = "id"
routes.quote.map.1 = "page"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign a defaul value to page parameter

```
routes.quotePage.route = :id/:page
routes.quotePage.defaults.module = default
routes.quotePage.defaults.controller = posts
routes.quotePage.defaults.action = single
routes.quotePage.defaults.page = 1
routes.quotePage.reqs.id = \d+
routes.quotePage.reqs.page = \d+
```

This will match both `http://domain.com/1` and `http://domain.com/1/page/1` or `http://domain.com/1/page/2`